# How to add my own plugin task to be executed after specific plugin of list of plugins?

Tags: gradle, vaadin

Consider following build pipeline:

```
15:21:50: Executing external task 'build'...
Hello from the GreetingPlugin
:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava NO-SOURCE
:copyMainKotlinClasses UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:findMainClass
:jar
:bootRepackage
:assemble
:compileTestKotlin UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
:copyTestKotlinClasses UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

I need to compile some SaaS theme which is located:

```
src/main/resources/VAADIN/themes/customtheme/customtheme.scss
```

into corresponding .css version in dir.

I presume that I need to make some gradle plugin which has to be executed:

between :jar  and :bootRepackage so that my .css ends up in final .jar.

So far I have this snippet:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: GreetingPlugin


class GreetingPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.task('hello') {
            println "Hello from the GreetingPlugin"
        }
    }
}
```

but as we can see the `GreetingPlugin` seem to be executed first. Is there a way I can insert my plugin to be executed at specific point in the build pipeline? How for example existing listed plugins know the order they have to be executed at?

Answer (score 1):

Gradle distinguishes between *configuration phase* and *execution phase*. Your full build script is executed in the *configuration phase* and the `apply` method of your plugin is called directly when applying the plugin. During the *execution phase* Gradle executes the task actions, `doFirst` and `doLast` closures of all tasks you listed as command line parameters and their task dependencies.

The task `hello` created by your plugin is not executed at all, it is only configured! During the task configuration, the output is printed to the command line. To move the `println` command to the *execution phase*, try this code:

```
project.task('hello') {
    doFirst {
        println "Hello from the GreetingPlugin"
    }
}
```

This way, you won't see the command line output, because the task still doesn't get executed. You could execute it by specifying the task name with your gradle command, like `gradle hello` or `gradle build hello`. To bind the execution of your task to another task, you can use the `dependsOn` method:

```
project.tasks['jar'].dependsOn('hello')
```

Note that this method will fail if your plugin is applied to a project that does not provide a `jar` task. In your final implementation you should try to integrate a more failsafe task dependency.